# How can one replace a set with a base set in nonstandard analysis?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, nonstandard-analysis

In the superstructure approach of nonstandard analysis, one builds the superstructure $V(X)$ as ($X$ being a set) :

1. $V_0(X)=X$
2. For $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$, $V_{n+1}(X)=V_n(X)\cup\mathcal{P}(V_n(X))$
3. $V(X)=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}V_n(X)$

In order to have a correspondance between basic set operations and formulas on $(V(X),\in)$, one has to suppose that $X$ is a base set, that is $\forall x\in X,x\cap V(X)=\emptyset \wedge x\neq\emptyset$.
How can one, in practise, replace a set by a base set of the same cardinal ? Can we even work in a base set of the same cardinal as if it were the first set ?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: In "Model Theory" by C. C. Chang and H. Jerome Keisler, it reads "It is easy to replace any set $X$ by a base set of the same size; see Exercise 4.4.1 for one method." (page 263, in the section 4.4) The problem is that this exercise does not help me to do that, even if I knew what it meant.

Answer (score 1):

You have to require the set to be a *base-set* to begin with.  Probably what Chang and Keisler mean by their remark is that there is a base-set in every cardinality (but I am not sure).  For example, if you consider a real number to be a Dedekind cut (i.e., pair of suitable subsets of the rational numbers), then you get a base set.  This point of view is developed in [these class notes](http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/tidg.pdf) (see chapter 15 there).